# host dotnetnuke application and database

Tags: hosting, dotnetnuke

Is there any special steps to host the dotnetnuke application and database on ftp server, if any then provide the steps to be follow to host dotnetnuke application..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you have a web server that you would like to install DNN on via FTP? If so, the answer is not without some sort of remote access. You'll need to have some sort of remote access to the server to do a full installation as you'll have to configure IIS to serve the website and configure the file system permissions in order for DNN to make it through the install process.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot host DNN on an FTP server.

You require an IIS Server and you must have access to configure that server to properly run the DNN application.